# git-clang-format-15 exlude json files

Tags: json, clang, clang-format

I have a large cpp project that should be checked with clang-format-15 but only between two commits.
For this I use the command

```
git-clang-format-15 --binary /usr/bin/clang-format-15 --diff commit_a commit_b
```

This works great till a json file gets changed, because there is no language config in .clang-format for Json.
If a json file got changed the git-clang-format-15 exits with error code 2 and does not scan any cpp files.
If I add

```
Language: Json
DisableFormat: true
```

the output does not include any json findings but the exit code is still 1, which is bad for automation.
I tried to create a .clang-format-ignore file with *.json but this file seams to be ignored.

Is there a way to exclude json files without an exit code -ne 0 or any way to get the .clang-format-ignore file to work?

Thx

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to put multiple languages settings in a single .clang-format file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62599833/how-to-put-multiple-languages-settings-in-a-single-clang-format-file)

Comment: No, sadly not. I know how to put multiple language configs in one file but I don't know how to configure clang-format to skip/ignore/exclude json files.